# regexp - combine two classes

Tags: ruby

I have a string and want to remove all non-symbolic characters (exclude ' ').  So if I have a "some, - another" I want to get "some  another".

I can use `s.gsub(/\W/, '')` to remove all non-symbolic characters, but it remove spaces ' ' also.

I can use `s.gsub(/\S/, '')` to remove all non-spaces, but it removes all symbolic characters.

How can I combine this two conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
s = "some, -  another"
s.gsub(/[^\s\w]/, '')
> "some  another"
```